# Android Responsive Design Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I've been working on an android application on Titanium lately and i've come upon an issue.

What i'm struggling with is making a specific view responsive.

I want to show like 15-20 buttons on a view but i don't want it to be scrollable.
Now if i use around 50dpi which is the recommended for buttons on some smaller screens i miss some of them.

How should i approach this? Should i use % of the device width and height which i get like

```
function PixelsToDPUnits(ThePixels) {
    if ( Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.dpi > 160 )
        return (ThePixels / (Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.dpi / 160));
    else 
        return ThePixels;
}

Ti.App.deviceWidth = PixelsToDPUnits(Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth);
Ti.App.deviceHeight = PixelsToDPUnits(Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight);
```

Should i create say 4-5 different views and load the right one according to the user's DPI?

What's the most correct way to approach this.

THanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is what you want to archive but you can work with `android:layout_weight`.
If you got 2 Buttons and both have a weight of 1 each of them will always cover 50% of the screen. Weather or not my answer helps please post your xml so we can be more specific about your Problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I follow:

1. Get the aspect ratio(width/height) of the button so that it is not squished or stretched.
2. Divide the available height by the no of buttons. Add some top and/or bottom padding. This is the height of each button
3. Width of button=height*aspect_ratio

This way you can fit buttons on any screens including tablets